# Highchart TypeScript using Angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, highcharts

I'm getting stuck to save ***const variable data*** using Highcharts, TypeScript and Angular1.5.
This works though, doesn't show up each data.
Does anyone have any ideas to solve this?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you so much,
Takahiro

```
    class MSSPiesController {

      private chartData:{
        availability?:IPieData//data type
        itemType?:IPieData//data type
        linkOwner?:IPieData//data type
      } = {};
      public chartTest;

      constructor(private $window:IWindowService,
                  private MSSCustomerService:IMSSCustomerService) {
        'ngInject';

        const data = this.MSSCustomerService.availabilityData;

        console.log("Customer service", data);

      }

      get availabilityData():IPieData {
        if (angular.isUndefined(this.chartData.availability)) {
This is the data what I want to use.

    MSSCustomerService.availabilityData
has interface in other page

          const data = this.MSSCustomerService.availabilityData;
          if (angular.isDefined(data)) {
            // this.chartData.availability = {
            // labels: ['up', 'down'],
            // data: [data.up, data.down],
            // colours: ['#058DC7', '#50B432'],

            // };
            this.reflow();
Here, the below using Highcharts

            this.chartTest = {
              options: {
                chart: {
                  type: 'pie',
                },
              },

              series: [{
I want use the above variable inside.

                data: [data.down, data.up]//Here, should show up the data     using the above variable
                // data: [10, 10]
              }],
              title: {
                text: false
              },
              loading: false
            };
          }
        }
        return this.chartData.availability;
      }
    }

    export const mssPiesComponent:IComponentOptions = {
      template: `
        <section class="card card-block m-t-10">
          <h2 class="display-8">
            Stats
          </h2>
          <p class="pull-right">Total Circuits: [[ $ctrl.numCircuits ]]</p>
          <pie-chart title="Availability" chart-data="$ctrl.availabilityData.data" labels="$ctrl.availabilityData.labels"     pie-colors="$ctrl.availabilityData.colours"></pie-chart> 
          <div>
          [[ $ctrl.availabilityData.labels ]]
          [[ $ctrl.availabilityData.data ]]
    </div>
<div>
<!--Pie chart using high chart-->
        <highchart id="chart1" config="$ctrl.chartTest"></highchart>
    </div>
    </section>
      `,
      controller: MSSPiesController,
      bindings: {
        numCircuits: '@',
      }
    };
```

Comment: Could you create a live demo in JSFiddle or Plunker?